# react-native reanimated's withSequence() not working properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

I have trying to do a sequence animation with loop but the sequences are not running in order as intended. Can anyone help in this to identify what is wrong and tell what to do right?

```js
const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => {
    return {
      transform: [
        {
          translateY: withRepeat(
            withSequence(
              withTiming(50, { duration: 200 }),
              withTiming(0, { duration: 200 }),
              withDelay(
                4000,
                withTiming(-50, { duration: 700 }, (finished) => {
                  if (finished) {
                    runOnJS(updateIndexWorklet)();
                  }
                }),
              ),
            ),
            -1,
            false,
          ),
        },
      ],
    };
function updateIndexWorklet() {
  setCurrentIndex((index) => index + 1);
}
```